# I have absolute position inside relative div, when I zoom in on to the device layout is overlapping the parent

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` relative position and inside of it an absolute position, but when I zoom in to the device layout, I have the problem that the absolute position overlapping the parent `div`.

Here the code:

```css
html,body{background:black;}
#dropzone{
  background:gray;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#child{
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background:green;
  left:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropzone">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

My result is like this:
[image: **this**]

It should be like this:
[image: **this**]

Comment: Use `%` rather than `px` to avoid overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not center elements ( I think this is what you are trying to do ) with `position: absolute;` Try with `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
html,body{background:black;}
#dropzone{
  background:gray;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

#child{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background:green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropzone">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tprsLLqy/

If you need different sizes for different `device sizes` you should use CSS mediaqueries like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   #child {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
}
```

See that working example here https://jsfiddle.net/tprsLLqy/1/ and try to resize the area where the result is in. The green box will get smaller and show up in orange.