# Zooming and postioning problems

Tags: css, position, zooming

I'm having an issue with positioning on a weeb OC website I'm making. The position of the picture (empty pic with borders) won't stay where it is when I zoom in and zoom out.

Here's how it is when at 100% zoom: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/777816226264383500/824975774159339550/unknown.png

Here's at 50% zoom: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/777816226264383500/824976068313088030/unknown.png

Also here is the code for the CSS of that image:

```
.me {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: maroon;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Weaboo! Nice work so far! The image is probably absolute based on the whole document, while it should better be absolute based on its parent element (by setting `position: relative to the parent, in your case probably the outmost round border around your content. Even better might be not using position, but margin or a grid layout. There have been similar discussions that might be helpful, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297525/i-have-absolute-position-inside-relative-div-when-i-zoom-in-on-to-the-device-la

Comment: You might want to post more code, not just the .me css. This will help us to help you. There is also a code editor much like codepen integrated in stackoverflow to ease providing a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to position `.me` relative to the parent if you won't do that, you're positioning is straight to the `body`.
Your HTML structure should look like this, where `.parent` is your image wrapper and `.me` is your picture:

```css
.parent{
position: relative;
}
.child{
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

If something is unclear let me know :)